# Woocommerce account page tabs are not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

I'm using woocommerce version 3.5.7 and created a storefront child theme. The problem is that tabs on My Account page are not working. When I click on these tabs it only refreshes the page. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYrUm.png)

I have searched but didn't find a proper solution I also see this guide https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/
 but not work. I have also selected account page for "My Account Page" in WooCommerce>>Settings>>Advanced>>[Page Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbeFd.png). I have switched to a twentyseventeen theme but also tabs on the account page not working. Here is the image for Account endpoints. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er456.png).

However, when I add end-points in Main Menu it works correctly. Here is the image [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7opru.png)

Comment: What do you see when you click on `addresses` and `Account details` ?

Comment: only page refreshes.

Comment: means account page refreshes only and nothing happens. Only when clicked on Log Out the link address changes to mysite/account/?_wpnonce=1e00adef31 but nothing happens means not logout.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem was due to Wpml Multilingual Plugin when I deactivate the plugin, woocommerce account tabs are working correctly.